# How to change Wither Skeleton skull drop rates (1.9)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm aware that it is possible to change loot tables for mobs in Minecraft 1.9, making [Ender Dragons drop an Elytra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yjqa4elLC8g) for example. This can be done either by creating a custom loot table or changing its entity data. For this example the command would be the following:

```
/entitydata @e[type=EnderDragon,tag=!hasTable] {ArmorDropChances:[0:1.1f,1:1.1f,2:1.1f,­3:1.1f],ArmorItems:[0:{},1:{},2:{id:elyt­ra,Count:1},3:{}],Tags:["hasTable"]}
```

Considering this, how would it be possible to make it so that Wither Skeletons always drop a skull?

Comment: For starters you can get a sword with an enchantment of fortune at like 100.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong I believe you mean looting.

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it with loot tables, but I can still help you. Get a **repeating** command block and input:

```
/scoreboard objectives add test stat.killEntity.WitherSkeleton
```

Next, in the same direction as that command block is facing, place a **chain** command block and input this:

```
execute @p[score_test_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon minecraft:wither_skull ~ ~ ~
```

which is good if your inventory is filling up fast, **or**

```
give @p[score_test_min=1] minecraft:skull 1 1
```

which is great if you're on a server and don't want people pinching your skulls. Next place another **chain** command block with:

```
/scoreboard players set @p[score_test_min=1] test 0
```

Note: Replace 'test' with the name of a scoreboard of your choosing, set the repeating command block to **always active** and **unconditional**, set the others to **always active** and **conditional**. This is multiplayer-friendly.

Bonus: If you use this for something more common (like cows and leather, for example), you might want to limit the availability by imposing a second requirement. To do this, put another **repeating** command block in place. Whichever repeating command block is closest to the chain command blocks can be a chain command block, but it **must** be set to conditional.

An example of a different kind of restriction is:

```
{SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:iron_axe,tag:{display:{Name:"Sacrificial Axe"}}}}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Summoning a `wither_skull` is not going to provide the player with wither skull items. A `wither_skull` entity is the projectile shot from the Wither boss. Also be aware that the question is referring to 1.9, where `stat.killEntity.WitherSkeleton` does not exist (and instead can only detect skeletons of all types).

Comment: thank you, i must have been using a more recent version by mistake.